# Persisting symfony2 entity datetime field: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I have an entity with this field:

```
  /**
   * @var \DateTime
   *
   * @Groups({"list", "details"})
   * @ORM\Column(name="timestamp", type="datetime")
   */
  private $timestamp;
```

And I have the following code:

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$myentity->setTimestamp($date); //Fails
$myentity->setTimestamp($date->getTimestamp()); //Also fails
```

I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]       
  Notice: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int
```

What is the proper way to store a datetime field with symfony and doctrine?

Comment: What does your setter look like? Did you previously use a `timestamp` type on the `$timestamp` property?

Comment: From memory (and I could be wrong), Doctrine doesn't use quotes around identifiers (table / column names), for example backticks in MySQL. In MySQL, `timestamp` is a reserved word. This may or may not have something to do with your problem. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

Answer (score -1):

There is possible than the oriented object method : `$date = new \DateTime(); $myentity->setTimestamp($date->getTimestamp());`  will be override by ORM.

See [DateTime::getTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

1. If you attempt with the procedural style : `$date = date_create(); $myentity->setTimestamp(date_timestamp_get($date));` have you any satisfied result ?

   See [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)
2. You can also attempt with `$date = new DateTime(); $myentity->setTimestamp($date->format('U')); // return seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)`

   See [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)